# Occurence of \r\ in a base64 converted image

Tags: swift, base64

I am trying to implement an api for uploading a photo. The input json is `{"Photo":"base64stringValue"}`.
The code used to convert the uiimage to base64string is

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
let imageStr = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

the conversion is successful. When I convert the `imageStr` obtained to an image I am able to obtain the correct image. However, on passing this string to `{"Photo":imageStr}` I get an error saying

```
SUCCESS: {
    Message = "The request is invalid.";
    ModelState =     {
        model =         (
            "An error has occurred."
        );
    };
```

On checking i found that base64string now contains random `\r\` values inserted in between.  Is this an issue? if yes, how can it be resolved?

Comment: Remove the `.lineLength64Characters` option ? – From the documentation: *"Set the maximum line length to 64 characters, after which a line ending is inserted."*

Comment: JSON strings can't have carriage returns or linefeeds in them. How are you actually creating the JSON string and how are you converting it back to a Base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

Objective C code i had used:

```
NSData *imgData4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);
NSString *base64Encoded = [imgData4 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```